# free is not happening and leads to memory overflow in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, malloc, free, instruments

In ARC XCode application, it uses native C library.

When the library functions are called continuously about 2000 times, the application stopped working on iPad device.

The 'Instrument' showed that, only 'Malloc' is getting accumulated and 'free' is not considered.

I have no clue, what happens with the 'free' call.

The code is given below:

Memory allocations:

> efHeapSize = EF_MIN_HEAPSIZE;   pEFHeap = (void
>   *)malloc(efHeapSize);
>
> cedHeapsize = heapMemorySize - efHeapSize;   pCEDHeap = (void
>   *)malloc(cedHeapsize);

Memory Free:

> if (pEFHeap != NULL)   {
>
> ```
> free (pEFHeap);
> pEFHeap = NULL;
> printf("pEFHeap freed \n");
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
>  if (pCEDHeap != NULL)   {
> free (pCEDHeap);
> pCEDHeap = NULL;
> printf("pCEDHeap freed \n");
> ```
>
> }

Comment: We would have to see your code to see if you call free. You could also check that free is called in your code by tracing the execution

Comment: You think we have a clue without seeing any code?

Comment: Be aware that ARC only works for Objective-C classes, for plain C you will need to release the memory your self.

Comment: Sorry. the actual source code is added in the question. Please check.

Comment: You should always check the return value of malloc() is not NOT

Comment: Are you sure there are no other allocations going on?

Comment: With instruments you can see exactly where malloc and free are called. Likely the free is not being called at all or the heap variables are not what you think they are.

Comment: Hello, found the leak present in the code. free() function is active. But, Instruments was showing total allocated memory. I didn't notice the current memory.